# fade function in an finished jquery gallery

Tags: jquery, fade

How i get in this code a fade effect? 
 When i click on the thumbs, the should fade the "big" picture!

This is the gallery demo http://workshop.rs/demo/gallery-in-4-lines/

```
<div class="box">
        <div id="panel"><img id="largeImage" src="pic/image_08_large.jpg" /> </div>
        <div class="text"> Die Idee und das Konzept</div>
        <div id="thumbs">
        <img src="pic/image_08_thumb.jpg" alt="1st image description" />
        <img src="pic/image_09_thumb.jpg" alt="2nd image description" />
        <img src="pic/image_10_thumb.jpg" alt="3rd image description" />

        </div>
```

Javascript

```
<script>

$('#thumbs').delegate('img','click', function(){
$('#largeImage').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb','large'));
$('#description').html($(this).attr('alt'));
});

</script>
```

css:

```
#thumbs { padding-top: 10px; overflow: hidden; }
#thumbs img, #largeImage { border: 1px solid gray; padding: 4px; 
background-color:white; cursor: pointer; }
#thumbs img { float: left; margin-left:60px;  margin-top:10px; }
#description { background: black; color: white; position: absolute; bottom: 0;   
padding: 10px 20px; width: 525px; margin: 5px; }
#panel { position: relative; }
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/  and http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/ Checks these links.

Comment: You want fadeIn/fadeOut gallery code?

Comment: thank for your fast answer!When i click on the little thumbs the big picture should fade. I am not familiar in javascript. This is my first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your code you cannot achieve the desired effect. So you'll need to:

- (...to get the desired efx:) have 2 images placed inside the 'panel' (you can *clone* the clicked one!)
- **Than you need to** 1: place the *clone* in place (needs to be hidden initially)
- 2: fade the *old* image
- 3: fade In the *clone* (new) image like:

### *[jsBin demo example](http://jsbin.com/ijedax/edit#javascript,html,live)*

```
$('.thumbs').on('click','img', function(){
        var $thisPanel = $(this).parents('.gallery').find('.panel');
        var clone = $(this).clone().hide();
        clone.appendTo($thisPanel);
        $thisPanel.find('img').eq(0).fadeTo(600,0,function(){
           $(this).remove();
        });
        clone.fadeTo(600,1);  
        $('.description').html($(this).attr('alt'));
});
```

Don't use **ID** for elements that are multiple on your page, instead use **class**. (See the demo):

```
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="panel">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/565x300/cf5" />
        <div class="description">First image description</div>
    </div>
 
    <div class="thumbs">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/565x300/cf5" alt="1st image description" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/565x300/f0f" alt="2nd image description" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/565x300/444" alt="3rd image description" />
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
  .thumbs { padding-top: 10px; overflow: hidden;}
    .thumbs img, .panel img {
     border: 1px solid gray;
     padding: 4px;
     background-color: white;
     cursor: pointer;
    }
  .panel img{
    position:absolute;
  }
    .thumbs img {
     float: left;
     margin-right: 3px;
    width:100px;
    }
    .description {
     background: black;
     color: white;
     position: absolute;
     z-index:2;
     bottom: 0;
     padding: 10px 20px;
     width: 525px;
     margin: 5px;
    }
  .panel { position: relative; height:310px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this out

```
$('#largeImage').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb','large'))
.hide().fadeIn('slow');
```

I haven't tried but i think this might works.

Comment: Then try .fadeIn('fast'); or what do you wanna show in your link? Can you elaborate?

Comment: My gallery is this ---http://workshop.rs/demo/gallery-in-4-lines/ when i click on the thumb next picture come normal. i want that it fade - a slow change-

Comment: See this I am sorry for the previous one. You can hide the image after source is given then fade in the image as in http://jsfiddle.net/Simplybj/ajNz7/. is this OK?

Comment: thanks for your code i think that is it. But i must change the id -#largeImage' with panel. when i take largeImage it doesn´t work!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Simplybj/ajNz7/3/  Do you have to change the id of
largeImage ?? why

Comment: i dont no why it doesn´t work. "<div id="panel"><img id="largeImage" src="pic/image_08_large.jpg" /> </div>" in this id"panel" is my id"largeImage". I change the id in your code and it work!

Comment: Can you make  a demo in jsfiddle.net so that i can help you.